# Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: c++, macos, linker, g++, terminal

I've recently moved over to a mac, and am struggling using the command line compilers. I'm using g++ to compile, and this builds a single source file fine. if I try to add a custom header file, when I try to compile using g++ I get undefined symbols for architecture i386. The programs compile fine in xCode however. Am I missing something obvious?

tried using g++ -m32 main.cpp... didn't know what else to try.

---

Okay, The old code compiled... Have narrowed it down to my constructors.

```
class Matrix{
public:
    int a;
    int deter;

    Matrix();
    int det();
};

#include "matrix.h"


Matrix::Matrix(){
    a = 0;
    deter = 0;
}

int Matrix::det(){
    return 0;

}
```

my error is 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Matrix::Matrix()", referenced from:
      _main in ccBWK2wB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

my main code has

```
#include "matrix.h"
int main(){
    Matrix m;

    return 0;
}
```

along with the usual

Comment: Consider editing your question to include your code, header file, and command line invocations.

Comment: and of course, the corresponding output ;)

Comment: Just to be clear, which architecture are you trying to build for? Is it x86_64?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you’ve got three files:

- matrix.h, a header file that declares the `Matrix` class;
- matrix.cpp, a source file that implements `Matrix` methods;
- main.cpp, a source file that defines `main()` and uses the `Matrix` class.

In order to produce an executable with all symbols, you need to compile both .cpp files and link them together.

An easy way to do this is to specify them both in your `g++` or `clang++` invocation. For instance:

```
clang++ matrix.cpp main.cpp -o programName
```

or, if you prefer to use `g++` — which Apple haven’t updated in a while, and it looks like they won’t in the foreseeable future:

```
g++ matrix.cpp main.cpp -o programName
```

Comment: Perfect. My problem was I wasn't including both of my source files in my command line. I didn't realise I had to do that.
Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking all over for this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

is not the case here, but it may happen to be the you forget to put the class name with ::

for example:

---

a good format:

foo.h

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo();
    void say();
private:
    int x;
};
```

foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(){
    this->x = 1;
}

void Foo::say(){
    printf("I said!\n");
}
```

---

a bad format

foo.h

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo();
    void say();
private:
    int x;
}
```

foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(){
    this->x = 1;
}

//I always mistake here because I forget to put the class name with :: and the xcode don't show this error.
void say(){
    printf("I said!\n");
}
```

Comment: wow, this one did it for me.. 
I'd say not enough c++ experience from my side. I thought the issue was with Xcode. But no, it was my mistake. Will be careful now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually define the Box constructor somewhere? (like Line.cpp)

Comment: And you are missing a `;` after the constructor declaration.

Comment: Constructor is defined. The code compiles in XCode. and no, have a ; at the end of that line, that's just a type sorry.

Comment: and you're including Matrix.cpp in the command line too, right?

Comment: No, I wasn't including matrix.cpp in the command line.
Thanks!