# c++ Compile error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined symbols for architecture i386:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818270/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386)

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "CorpusExp.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
ifstream infile("../DATA.txt");
string train_dir;   // The training data directory
infile>>train_dir;
train_dir=train_dir.substr(6,train_dir.length());

if (argc>1){
    if (strcmp(argv[1],"-s")){ // enter into CorpusExploration mode
        CorpusExp ce(train_dir,"all");   //<<=======LINE X!!!!!!!!
        //ce.calculate();
        if (argc>=3 && strcmp(argv[2],"-u")){ // check user stats
            cout<<"shit";
        }
        else if (argc>=3 && strcmp(argv[2],"-m")){ // check movie stats

        }else{ // check the all (default) stats

        }
    }else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-m")) {// enter into Recommendation mode

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

**If I include the LINE X, the main.cpp won't compile, the error message is:**

```
      Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "CorpusExp::CorpusExp(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [recommend] Error 1
```

**And here is my CorpusExp.cpp and CorpusExp.h:**

/* CorpusExporater header file
   Used for statistical purpose

*/

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>  // the Linux library to read the directories

class CorpusExp{
public:
    CorpusExp(const string&,const string&); // (dir_name, mode)
    void calculate();
    void display(ostream &out, const int&);    // print out the id's stat information

private:
    string _dir_name;
    int _movie_count;
    int _user_count;
    int _movie_rated_count[5]; // times of movie rated as 1,2,3,4,5
    float _movie_avg;   // total moview average rates
    string _mode; // the mode of current task
    int _id; // the id of current task

};

/*CorpusExporater cpp file
   Used for statistical purpose

*/
#include "CorpusExp.h"

CorpusExp::CorpusExp(const string &dir_name, const string &mode):
    _dir_name(dir_name),
    _mode(mode),
    _movie_count(0),
    _user_count(0)
{


}

void CorpusExp::calculate(){
    DIR *dpdf;
    struct dirent *epdf;

    dpdf = opendir(strdup(_dir_name.c_str()));
    if (dpdf!=NULL){
        while(epdf = readdir(dpdf)){
            cout<<epdf->d_name<<endl;
        }
    }
}
void CorpusExp::display(ostream &out, const int &id){

}
```

**I am barely new to c++, so I get very confused, don't know which part caused this problem. If I remove the LINE X, everything will just be fine, but if I declare the CorpusExp class in the main function, then it did not compile......**

here is the compile file:

```
# Makefile for Movie Recommendation--- HW5 of Search Engine 11-641
#   Yitong Zhou
#   Nov 19, 2012

#source code directory:
src=src
#obj code directory:
obj=obj


recommend: $(obj)/main.o $(obj)/CorpusExp.o
    g++ -o $@ $<
$(obj)/main.o: src/main.cpp src/CorpusExp.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@
$(obj)/CorpusExp.o: $(src)/CorpusExp.cpp $(src)/CorpusExp.h
    g++ -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf obj/*.o recommend
```

Comment: What does the compiler invocation look like?

Comment: It appears you're not compiling *and linking* your `CorpusExp.cpp` file into your program. the header definition and inclusion allows `main.cpp` to compile, but without the code from a compiled `CorpusExp.cpp` you will have unresolved externals.

Comment: Are you compiling with a similar to this:
g++ main.cpp CorpusExp.cpp -o program

Comment: I think I write g++ main.cpp -o program...

Comment: Try a simple command line compile without the makefile to make sure the makefile itself isn't the problem. cd src; g++ main.cpp CorpusExp.cpp -o recommend

Comment: Yes, it will compile, seems my makefile is not correct...

Comment: @YitongZhou Excellent. Glad we could help. I've supplied my suggestion as an answer if you'd like to accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simple command line compile without the makefile to make sure the makefile itself isn't the problem.

```
cd src; g++ main.cpp CorpusExp.cpp -o recommend
```

Comment: Did you get your makefile working or do you need help with it?