# Compiler error on static class variable

Tags: c++

In the `public` section of my class declaration, I have this:

```
static float m_screenWidth;
static float m_screenHeight;
```

I can then set them to whatever I want in the class constructor or elsewhere, however, the compiler fails when I use them, saying:

`Undefined symbols for architecture`

This is noted on any line in which I try to access these members. In class methods, I access them by name. In non-member functions I access them with the `className::` prefix. Doesn't matter, they are not enjoyed. Any advice?

Worth noting that they are *not* getting "undeclared" errors, so they are recognized to some degree.

Comment: "Undefined symbol" is a linker, not a compiler error. How do you actually define them?

Comment: [**have a look on this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818270/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message is a linker failure message, not a compiler failure message. It is stating that it cannot find the definitions of the variables.

In the `public` section they are *declarations*. They must be *defined*, exactly once, outside of the `class` definition:

```
float className::m_screenWidth;
float className::m_screenHeight;
```

Answer (score 2):

You ***declared*** them in the header file. You also have to ***define*** them in a `.cpp` file somewhere:

```
float MyClass::m_screenWidth;
float MyClass::m_screenHeight;
```

That will tell the compiler to actually reserve space and create symbols for these static variables.